# Decode and get data from Branch link programmatically in Ionic

Tags: deep-linking, branch.io, ionic-plugins

In my Ionic 5 app, I am trying to provide functionality for users to copy a Branch.io link from anywhere and paste/type it in the App. I want to use the link and trigger the same action when it is clicked to get the data and perform the action in the App.

I am using Ionic [BranchIo](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/branch-io) plugin.

I am not getting any Branch method to do this action and decode the link. Method `branch.initSession()` will only work if the link is clicked.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to read the link data associated to the deep link you can use the Branch [Deep Linking API](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/deep-linking-api#reading-existing-deep-links) for this use case.

Example Request Payload -

```
curl -XGET 'https://api2.branch.io/v1/url?url=https://example.app.link/WgiqvsepqF&branch_key=key_live_xxxxxxxx'
```